# Swift solution for web sockets to use https instead of ws or wss?

Tags: swift, websocket, socket.io, stream, starscream

I’m trying to open a connection to a url that is constantly streaming JSON objects (1 per line)

currently the data looks like:

```
{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
{"a": 4, "b": 5, "c": 6}
```

from my understanding, valid json would be:

```
[
  {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}, 
  {"a": 4, "b": 5, "c": 6}
]
```

I figured web sockets were the way to go but the url is in https and not ws or wss like how all the tutorials I’ve been digging up have been using.

Is there a way to convert https to wss or another way I can go about accomplishing the same task?

I’ve tried using StarScream and SocketIO but haven’t had much success. I ran into the same problem when using https://

Comment: Why https if you plan to use sockets?

Comment: That’s just what the url is, I did not make it. I’m only trying to figure out a way to connect to it. Sorry if I was unclear, I’m new to all this